# Hive - remove trailing zeros

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I'm trying to remove trailing zeros from a string in HIVE, for example `5634000 -> 5634`

I have tried

```
SELECT RTRIM('1230','0');
```

but Hive throws the following error:

```
Error while compiling statement:
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10014]: line 41:46
Wrong arguments ''0'': rtrim requires one value argument. Found :2
```

I have also tried:

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE('ABCA','+A$','')
```

but it is also throwing an exception.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please provide us with some code, showing what you already tried? Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `RTRIM` is for trimming white space from the right-hand-side of a String, so it won't work here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE('5634000','0+$',''); -> 5634
```

`0+` matches the character 0 literally
 `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
`$` asserts position at the end of the string

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE('ABCA','A+$','')
```

Your regex expression (`+A$`) in second parameter is invalid.

https://regex101.com/r/SzNkKJ/1

Comment: Also look at the question from this post.  He said this has an error. FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10014]: Line 1:7 Wrong arguments '''':

Comment: The SemanticException is connected with the first attempt OP tried (SELECT RTRIM('1230','0'); ) The second error was connected with wrong regexp. I have tested my solutoin on hive 2.1.1. Which version of hive are you using?

Comment: if he said it has an error, why would you put it as answer? QUoute: I have also tried:

select REGEXP_REPLACE('ABCA','+A$','')
but it is also throwing an exception.

Comment: Yes, REGEXP_REPLACE('ABCA','+A$','') will throw an exception because regex expression in second parameter is invalid. Mine is slightly different: select REGEXP_REPLACE('ABCA','A+$',''). Plus quantifier is after A. You can use website I have provided to try different regex expressions.

Comment: Thank you Luk ... your link answer both are use full !

Answer (score 2):

One way is to `cast` the reversed `string` as `int` (which will remove leading zeroes in the reversed string) and casting back to `string` and reversing it again.

```
select reverse(cast(cast(reverse(column_name) as int) as string))
from tbl
```